# Error when routing to the "show" page with Ember.Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

This error is driving me **crazy**. I tried freenode #emberjs before asking here.

I have the following routing scheme:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    //...

    showPost: Ember.State.transitionTo('post'),

    posts: Ember.Route.extend({
       route: '/posts',
       connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
             router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({ outletName: 'page', name: 'posts', context: App.Post.find()});
             this._super(router, context);
       }
    }),

    post: Ember.Route.extend({
         route: '/posts/:post_id',
         connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
             router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({ outletName: 'page', name: 'post', context: post});
             this._super(router, post);
         }
    })
});
```

The `posts` route that shows the list of posts works fine. Navigating to a specific post, for example `posts\1` I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object <App.Post:ember6957> has no method 'addArrayObserver'
```

If needed, take a look at the stack trace: http://pastebin.com/eEJ2hMAV

The router sets the content property of App.router.postController to the post that the user is clicking on. In the console,

```
App.router.postController.get('content') instanceof DS.Model
```

returns `true`. And it tries to call `addArrayObserver` on this `content`, but DS.Model isn't extending Ember.Array (where addArrayObserver is defined).

On the other hand,

```
App.router.postsController.get('content') instanceof DS.RecordArray
```

returns `true`, and calling `addArrayObserver` on this `content` works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I miss some context from your code, I built a working example based on your code.

to see the code, http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/jLbry/

to see the routes: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/jLbry/show

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/jkkK3/6/    It looks like the problem was that I extend the controller for a single post as `App.PostController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()`, where it should extend ObjectController. Silly error, thanks a lot!